# How to handle "bytes" in QML?

Tags: qt, byte, qml

Considering :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativebasictypes.html
there is no strict equivalent of "byte" in QML.

Nonetheless, I have to manipulate some datas in a whole project, and QML file are an intermediate for communications. And some of these datas are some byte...

What can I do ?

(found some links about QVariant but I don't feel like I can use it in QML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't actually use those bits in QML you might be able to save in an integer and then get those back.

Answer (score 1):

I've already seen your question in Qt forum, but left with the intention that someone with better knowledge can help you.

Could you please tell about your necessity to use a **byte** in QML. If it is going to be standalone application, you can handle (and only can - I think) it using a C++ datatype like **char** and display/present it from the QML side.

If it just going to be a QML file, then I think you have to create a byte like object with Qt C++ and use it to store the values.

I definitely don't think that QML can handle file operations, neither can it access any serial port services. So the C++ can handle these situations without any difficulties.